# Relation between station and Ad Object

Tags: active-directory

let's say I have a station which is connected to my network but is not a part of the domain. If I add the station to the domain, meaning create an AD Object, is there a property in the object that connects me with the station?

I mean except the hostname. It doesn't count really because it's easy to change.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "station"? A windows computer?

Comment: Yess sorry, I did mean a windows computer

Comment: Creating the computer account object in the directory is not enough to establish the relationship. You need to actively configure domain membership on the workstation itself (eg. by calling `Add-Computer` or `netdom join ...` or `Win32_ComputerSystem.JoinDomainOrWorkGroup()` and providing appropriate domain credentials)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply. I'm wondering though: if an AD object already exists, how can you determine  what computer is it connected to? Is there a property in the object that can connect me to the computer except the name?

Comment: No. It's like a bouncer's guest list at a nightclub - there's a bunch of names and whoever shows up and proves that they're the ones on the guest list (this is possible because the DC and computer exchange a shared secret during the join operation) must be the computer